# The form of news title

Tags: present-participles

When reading news titles in English, I always notice a strange form in the title, examples :

1. Quarantine bringing out creativity for millions on TikTok (source: CNN)
2. Meet the clown lifting spirits in the time of coronavirus (source: CNN)

I said strange because there is no "to be" verb before these 2 verbs ("bringing out" and "lifting"). (I supposed the time is present continuous but with "to be" verb cancellation)

Is it a special form of writing news titles in English?

Comment: The news headlines and titles are written as concise as possible. However, the full form of the examples you mentioned are not like "to be bringing out" and "to be lifting", but "is bringing out" and "who is lifting".

Comment: Headlines, captions of photos, warning signs, and other places where concision is desirable, often use a form of English where some words are omitted: it is often called [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Comment: @Cardinal Actually I meant by "to be" its variants (is, are, was, were), so it is "is" in my case.

Comment: Cardinal & Coline Fine Thank you both you helped me a lot